# Perform UIActionSheet action's on different View Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiactionsheet

I have a slide out menu in my app, which has a button that will display a UIActionSheet. This slide out menu just partly covers whatever view controller you previously were on.

```
- (void)cameraButtonPushed:(UIButton *)sender
{   
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Create String" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo", @"Choose from Library", nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

    //[actionSheet showInView:self.parentViewController.view];
}
```

As you can see I have tried two ways of showing the action sheet and they both appear to work the same.

The problem that I'm having has to do with the action sheet buttons actually working. It shows up in the parent view controller (view controller that you were on), but if I press any of the buttons they do not work.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        EditVC *newEditVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editVC"];
        [editVC setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        [self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:newEditVC animated:YES];

      //[self.navigationController pushViewController:newEditVC animated:YES];
    } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        EditVC *newEditVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"editVC"];
        [editVC setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
        [self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:newEditVC animated:YES];

      //[self.navigationController pushViewController:newEditVC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Both of the above methods are in the same menu view controller where the button is pressed. I put some break points to test it out and the action sheet delegate method is being called. The if statement is working correctly, but the new VC's are not being pushed onto the navigation controller the way they should. It just runs over those lines and nothing happens. I have also tried setting it up in a way that parent view controller's also have the `actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method in them, but that method is not called.

I believe that it has to do with setting up the actionSheet with an improper delegate, but I don't know for sure.

How can I call this action sheet from one view controller, display it and have actions performed in another? I have it appearing in the correct VC, but the action's aren't working.

Comment: While debugging with breakpoint, check self.parentViewController.navigationController, it might have been Nil.

Comment: @chandu You're right. Both the self.parentViewController.navigationController and self.navigation controller return nil. What should I do to access the nav controller of the parent?

Comment: Is your app's window's rootViewController is navigationController?

Comment: @chandu It is, but when I use code to access the rootViewController it comes back as nil. I use [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow and then access the rootViewController through that. Getting the rootVC from that call comes back as nil?

Comment: How can there won't be a rootView, can you share your code in github or bitbucket?

Comment: @chandu when I access the window and the rootVC from that window there is no existing navigationViewController. Everything up until that point comes back, but the navVC returns nil.

Comment: Is the window.rootViewController nil?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45399/discussion-between-jonathan-and-chandu)